# Trouble updating Angular view based on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML markup which is part of a Bootstrap input group.  What I'm trying to do is update the text that appears on the menu selector based on what option is clicked.  So the text I initially set to {{ searchBy }} and then I call a function on ng-click to update it.  Initially the button shows nothing because searchBy is undefined, but I'd like it to show the first option.  If I click one of the menu options, searchBy is updated on the scope, but then it's immediately changed back to undefined.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ searchBy }} <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a ng-href="#" ng-click="setSearchBy('number', 'Receipt')">Receipt</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#" ng-click="setSearchBy('freightBill', 'BOL')">BOL</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#" ng-click="setSearchBy('customerOrderNumber', 'Sales Order')">Sales Order</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#" ng-click="setSearchBy('purchaseOrderNumber', 'PO')">PO</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#" ng-click="setSearchBy('trailer', 'Trailer')">Trailer</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my controller.  I have a watch setup on the searchBy property that just outputs the old and new value to the console and I can see this gets called twice when I click a menu option.

```
angular.module('webappApp')
  .controller('ReceiptsCtrl', function ($scope, receipts) {

    $scope.setSearchBy = function(searchByProperty, searchBy) {
      $scope.searchBy = searchBy||'Receipt';
      $scope.searchByProperty = searchByProperty||'number';
    };

    $scope.$watch('searchBy', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.debug(oldValue + ' -> ' + newValue);
    });
  });
```

Comment: The problem does not seem to lie in the code you posted. This plunker works as expected. http://plnkr.co/edit/mqZyUc7e7kkQTVdP3OeJ?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's happening then...

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down to the menu options being <a> tags.  By simply changing one of the options to have the ng-click on the <li> tag and removing the <a> tag, it worked.  Although that doesn't explain why it worked ok in your plunker.  Maybe I have to intercept the event and prevent the default link behaviour?

Comment: I could help better if you updated a plunker to reflect your problem.

Comment: After a bit of trial and error, I managed to get it working by passing $event to my setSearchBy function.  Then inside my function, I call preventDefault().  So the link behaviour gets intercepted and no routing occurs in Angular.